# gradle exec: how to print error output?

Tags: gradle, exec, message

Gradle task: start a service

```
task startService(type: Exec) {
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    errorOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'net', 'start', 'serviceFoo'

    doLast {
        println standardOutput.toString()
        println errorOutput.toString()
    }

}
```

running `"net start serviceFoo`" will print "access denied" message on windows.
but `gradle startService`, no message is printed.

### UPDATE

tried it on Windows command prompt (admin):

```
 commandLine 'net', 'start', 'serviceFoo'
```

Error message:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':startService'.
> Process 'command 'net'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

On command prompt (admin):

```
 net start serviceFoo
```

Successful.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `commandLine 'net' 'start' 'serviceFoo'`? It seems like 'Access denied' is the error output of the `net` process, not the `cmd` process.

Comment: updated question. thanks.

Comment: According to Gradle source code(`org.gradle.process.ExecResult` which represents the result of running an external process) there is no such a functionality in Gradle and we need to look at the appropriate OS's daemon log ("windows logs" in your case)

Answer (score 4):

Gradle will by default throw an exception and terminate when receiving non-zero result codes from commands. You can disable this by setting the property

```
ignoreExitValue true
```

in your task. Normally you'd also wanna check for it yourself then, eg.

```
doLast {
  if (execResult.getExitValue() != 0) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: In case it isn't obvious to others... One option within the doLast block is to throw new GradleException("Error message") there. This way error output is written to the console and the Gradle build still exits where it should.